# Installing IntelliJ IDEA messes up Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, ide

After installed IntelliJ IDE on my Macbook the UI for creating new Android app became like this:

[image]

Which is identical with the new project UI of IntelliJ.

I tried uninstall IntelliJ and removed all its preference folders and then try to uninstall and reinstall Android Studio but the problem haven't gone.
Could anyone please shed some light for me to not reset my Macbook :v

Comment: You are running IntelliJ IDEA, not Android Studio.

Comment: Man I must know which app I open. I open AS but it look like IntelliJ and that's the problem :(.

Comment: So, the Welcome Screen dialog says it's Android Studio? Can you attach a screenshot of that?

Comment: Thank @CrazyCoder! yeah it says Android Studio. It seems like installing IntelliJ will affect some of the Android plugins which contain the Android project templates. I just need to re-download them to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I had to uninstall IntelliJIdea and android studio, although its not only sending the app to the thrash. You also need to delete:

> ~/Library/Application Support/IntelliJIdea2018.2
>   ~/Library/Caches/IntelliJIdea2018.2
>   ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea2018.2
>   ~/Library/Logs/IntelliJIdea2018.2

take a look at this: https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-intellij-on-mac

the same goes for android:

> ~/Library/Android (by removing this folder you will also uninstall Android SDK)
>   ~/Library/Preferences/AndroidStudio
>   ~/Library/Preferences/com.google.android
>   ~/Library/Preferences/com.android
>   ~/Library/Application/Support/AndroidStudio
>   ~/Library/Logs/AndroidStudio
>   ~/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio

https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-android-studio-on-mac

that solved my issue